# reportschannel is undefined (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

I am making a report/bug command and got this error:

```
reportschannel is undefined
```

Here is my full code:

```js
switch (args[0]) {
  case "report":
    message.delete({ timeout: 3000 });
    let target =
      message.mentions.members.first() ||
      message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
    if (!target)
      return message.channel
        .send("Please provide a user that you wish to report")
        .then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 15000 }));
    if ((args[1] === target, args[2] === reason)) {
      message.channel.send(
        "Your report has been filled to the staff team. Thank you for reporting!"
      );
      reportsChannel.send(
        `**${message.author.username}** has reported **${target.user.username}** for **${reason}**.`
      );
    }
    var reason = args.slice(2).join(" ");
    if (!reason)
      return message.channel
        .send(
          `Please provide a reason for reporting **${target.user.username}**`
        )
        .then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 15000 }));

    let reportsChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
      (x) => x.name === "wide log"
    );

    break;
}
```

I'm not quite sure what's going wrong in my code; am I overlooking something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable must be above where you use it. For example:

```
let reportsChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.name === "wide log")

reportsChannel.send(...)
```

By the way, Discord channel names cannot contain space. Use `wide-log` instead of `wide log`